# server path for mamp local server

Tags: php, mamp

Im trying to setup the 140dev twitter api, and as part of the config i need to specify the server paths to certain files, they give the example of

```
// Directory for db_config.php
define('DB_CONFIG_DIR', '/var/www/html/140dev/db/');
```

and

```
// External URL for Javascript code in browsers to call the framework with Ajax
define('AJAX_URL', 'http://yoursite.com/140dev/');
```

But im not sure of what to replace these with as im running the test site using mamp locally under - `http://localhost:8888/twitter-api/140dev/`

any ideas what to put for the two above examples ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of trail and error i found the solution, you need to set the server path to the location of mamp so you for the above examples you would write -

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/140dev/db/
```

and

```
http://localhost:8888/140dev/
```